# Especificador de invalidación desconocido #C3646

Tags: variables, vscode, class, compilador

Buen día, llevo bastante tiempo programando en c++ pero siempre he utilizado Dev C++ pero por pura curiosidad quise intentar a programar en visual studio, e hice un programa pequeño con una clase pero me devuelve el error C3646 cuando se instancia la clase, donde me dice que todas mis variables ("Nombre", "Direccion", "Edad") tienen un especificador desconocido

he intentado ejecutar el código en dev C++ y ejecuta perfectamente, también busqué especificaciones sobre el error en internet y no encontré algo de mucha ayuda, podría pensar que es cuestión del compilador pero no lo se, no manejo muy bien la cuestión de los compiladores.
mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
class Clase1
{   
    public:
    
        string nombre; // #C3646 Error de invalidación desconocido
        string direccion; // #C3646 Error de invalidación desconocido
        int edad; // #C3646 Error de invalidación desconocido

    
    int setNombre(string pNombre) {
        this->nombre = pNombre;
    }

    string getNombre() {
        return this->nombre;
    }

};
```

Comment: Incluye la librería `#include <string>` y especifica de esta manera `std::string nombre;`, ¿lo intentaste de esta forma?

Comment: gracias, en lugar de colocar std:: antes de cada string le coloqué el using namespace std; y quedó solucionado, pero aún no comprendo por qué en dev me funcionó tal y como está pero en visual no, pero muchas gracias, si me quedó solucionado